# I need vba code for showing next entry in other sheet cell

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1z6j.jpg)[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dmCz.jpg]

I want when ever i click next button it should show in next to serial cell and next cell down as per given in different sheet

[image]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Can you provide some more information on what your data looks like and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for not clear, i have two sheets one is invoice and second is sheet4, in invoice sheet where serial no 0000 (c9). I want when ever i click next button my serial no should change from 0000 to 0721 and then again i click next button then it should change to 0730 and go on like that hope i clear now something

Comment: and other sheet name is sheet4 and its range start from b3 to b535

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried so many time and different code but i am to much confuse and i don't know what to do so i just recorded macro

Comment: Don´t add code in a comment. Just edit you question and include whatever you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this above conversation in understood that you need some excel VBA code for the NEXT button by pressing you would like to show the next entry of Sheet4(b3:b535) at the sheet invoice c9 cell

```
Dim previousRow As Long
Sub nextrow()

    If previousRow = 0 Then
        previousRow = 1 '<--starts at row 1
    Else
        previousRow = previousRow + 1 '<--increases of 1 each click
    End If
    Sheets("invoice").Cells(9, 3) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(previousRow, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: yes you are right i want this exact . i tried your code and i got error expected end sub

Comment: i write end sub again for end if but now its not working i mean no error and nothing changed

Comment: @Shaharyaroffice its working for me.. please try to copy from Dim to end sub

Comment: thanks alot for this help , its working now but i have one more issue like its just showing next entry it doesn't matter from where i started serial if i want to again show from start  its not showing me 0721 to 0730 its just adding +1 and right now its showing 0751 serial

Comment: can you write code for previous button same as previous row - 1

Comment: @Shaharyaroffice for previous just reverse the code

Comment: i tried but its not working i don't know exactly what to do so please if you can it will be great help me thanks in advance

Comment: @Shaharyaroffice code provided please check

Comment: Angad, your code is ok, but it is not checking which value you have on C9 cell, it is just beginning from the first one and Shaharyar office needs to go to the next whatever serial is there.

Comment: David exactly sir that's what i need

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your button.

```
Dim Serial, i as Long

Serial = Worksheets("invoice").Cells(9, 3).Value

For i= 3 to Worksheets("sheet4").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(i, 2).Value = Serial Then
        Serial= i
        i= Worksheets("sheet4").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    End If
Next

If Serial= Worksheets("invoice").Cells(9, 3).Value Then
    MsgBox "There is no more serial numbers"
Else
    Worksheets("invoice").Cells(9, 3).Value = Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(Serial + 1, 2).Value
End If
```

If there is no match, it will show you a MsgBox saying `"There is no more serial numbers"`.

Comment: thanks alot for the help i tried this code but nothing changed and i don't need match

Comment: Nothing changes?  Please, could you exactly explain what is not working? I duplicate your samples and it work on my computer...

Comment: i mean it didn't change anything in any cell

Comment: Already fixed... I placed cell I3 instead of C9... (3,9) <> (9,3)...je je je

Comment: cool thanks for the help i already got what i need and later i will try your

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the previous row

```
Dim previousrow As Long
Sub previousrow1()
    If previousrow = 0 Then
        previousrow = 535 '<--starts at row 1
    Else
        previousrow = previousrow - 1 '<--increases of 1 each click
    End If
    Sheets("invoice").Cells(9, 3) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(previousrow, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Angad, your code is ok, but it is not checking which value you have on C9 cell, it is just beginning from the first one and Shaharyar office needs to go to the next whatever serial is there.

Comment: it can't be previous from current invoice no which is in c9? its started previous from b535